# Trying to access ipython notebook running on virtual machine

Tags: python, ipython, virtualbox, vmware, jupyter

I would really appreciate some help here, basically I'm learning to use tensorflow, I've decided that the easiest way to go about this would be to install ubuntu on either VMware and/or Virtualbox and then access the ipython notebook (came with anaconda) through the browser on the host computer.

I have successfully installed both vmware and virtualbox, I downloaded a ubuntu image and also successfully installed anaconda on both, I get it to work without a problem on both VMs and even installed tensorflow.

Some research online on how to expose the ipython to the host machine suggested port forwarding or ssh tunneling, none of these have worked (very likely I'm doing it wrong). Can someone please help? think of me as a newbie.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly with ssh in python ? can you show us some code ?

Comment: I don't think port forwarding has anything to do with it. Can you determine the IP address of the VM? Can you `ping` that address from the host operating system? If so, it's probably just a jupyter config issue. See my answer for a relevant link.

Comment: @shotgunner SSH forwarding is this process of forwarding connections to a port through SSH. The question isn't trying to do SSH in python.

Comment: There's several blogs for getting setup in Windows (i assume that's why you need a VM). For example, https://medium.com/@Rapchik/running-google-s-deep-learning-course-material-under-windows-82d468b6d5be#.7umqm7nzb and http://data-shaker.com/docker-tensorflow-with-jupyter-notebook-on-windows/

Comment: Thanks for the response, Yes I pinged the ip addresses of the VM and packets sent and received OK. Any more ideas? Also I tried both NAT and bridged network connection, none works.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you must edit the jupyter configuration file to allow network access to the notebook server. See this link: http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/public_server.html for details. (Even if it is not a "public" server, you still intend to access the notebook server living in the VM from the host machine via a network connection...)

Here is a quotation from the linked documentation that indicates by default, you can only access the notebook via the localhost.

> By default, a notebook server runs locally at 127.0.0.1:8888 and is accessible only from localhost. You may access the notebook server from the browser using http://127.0.0.1:8888.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I followed that too exactly, I know everything I did there works because when accessing ipython from inside the vm, it now asks for a password and I have to add 'https' to localhost, both because I amended the ssl section as well as the password section of ipython's config file. I'm completely at a loss, the reason I need the VM is to access tensorflow inside ipython from the host PC. Sad thing is I have many times used Azure vm to host without a problem and the difference I can think of is port forwarding.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, it is solved. After posting my last message about the only thing different being port forwarding, I decided to follow that though and that was all was needed, there's a port forwarding section in the NAT settings in virtualbox. No such thing in VMware player though sadly

Comment: @NordeenSij i'm facing same problem, can u pl guide me?